# Convert UTF-8 varbinary(max) to varchar(max)

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a varbinary(max) column with UTF-8-encoded text that has been compressed. I would like to decompress this data and work with it in T-SQL as a varchar(max) using the UTF-8 capabilities of SQL Server.

I'm looking for a way of specifying the encoding when converting from varbinary(max) to varchar(max). The only way I've managed to do that is by creating a table variable with a column with a UTF-8 collation and inserting the varbinary data into it.

```
DECLARE @rv TABLE(
    Res varchar(max) COLLATE Latin1_General_100_CI_AS_SC_UTF8 
)

INSERT INTO @rv
SELECT SUBSTRING(Decompressed, 4, DATALENGTH(Decompressed) - 3) WithoutBOM
FROM
    (SELECT DECOMPRESS(RawResource) AS Decompressed FROM Resource) t
```

I'm wondering if there is a more elegant and efficient approach that does not involve inserting into a table variable.

**UPDATE:**

Boiling this down to a simple example that doesn't deal with byte order marks or compression:

I have the string "Hello " UTF-8 encoded without a BOM stored in variable `@utf8Binary`

```
DECLARE @utf8Binary varbinary(max) = 0x48656C6C6F20F09F988A
```

Now I try to assign that into various char-based variables and print the result:

```
DECLARE @brokenVarChar varchar(max) = CONVERT(varchar(max), @utf8Binary)
print '@brokenVarChar = ' + @brokenVarChar

DECLARE @brokenNVarChar nvarchar(max) = CONVERT(varchar(max), @utf8Binary)
print '@brokenNVarChar = ' +  @brokenNVarChar 

DECLARE @rv TABLE(
    Res varchar(max) COLLATE Latin1_General_100_CI_AS_SC_UTF8 
)

INSERT INTO @rv
select @utf8Binary

DECLARE @working nvarchar(max)
Select TOP 1 @working = Res from @rv

print '@working = ' + @working
```

The results of this are:

```
@brokenVarChar = Hello ðŸ˜Š
@brokenNVarChar = Hello ðŸ˜Š
@working = Hello
```

So I am able to get the binary result properly decoded using this indirect method, but I am wondering if there is a more straightforward (and likely efficient) approach.

Comment: At least one example (compressed) value would really help us help you here.

Comment: @Larnu, thanks for the suggestion. I added an example script.

Comment: Very good question. [According to the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#output-collation), `CAST(@utf8Binary AS varchar(max)) COLLATE Latin1_General_100_CI_AS_SC_UTF8` *should* work, but it doesn't.

Comment: I am honestly getting some very odd results here in my sandbox environment... Have a look at this [animated GIF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/woe8U.gif) where the behaviour of a function is one database changes because I created another database;

Comment: SSMS, however, does not replicate the behaviour ([Animated GIF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/URo7i.gif)) so looks like an ADS flaw.

Comment: If anyone is interested, [Github Issue](https://github.com/microsoft/azuredatastudio/issues/12919) in regards to the ADS behaviour.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't like this solution, but it's one I got to (I initially thought it wasn't working, due to what appears to be a bug in ADS). One method would be to create a new database in a UTF8 collation, and then pass the value to a function in that database. As the database is in a UTF8 collation, the default collation will be different to the local one, and the correct result will be returned:

```sql
CREATE DATABASE UTF8 COLLATE Latin1_General_100_CI_AS_SC_UTF8;
GO
USE UTF8;
GO
CREATE OR ALTER FUNCTION dbo.Bin2UTF8 (@utfbinary varbinary(MAX))
RETURNS varchar(MAX) AS
BEGIN
    RETURN CAST(@utfbinary AS varchar(MAX));
END
GO
USE YourDatabase;
GO
SELECT UTF8.dbo.Bin2UTF8(0x48656C6C6F20F09F988A);
```

This, however, isn't particularly "pretty".

Comment: @Tornhoof If you came up with a different solution, then you should post it as a new answer. Though the above looks like it'll be passed as a multi-line scalar function which will likely be less performant

Comment: Yes it is likely slower, so no there is no need to post a new answer, your answer is I think still the best solution to the problem.

Comment: I honestly hope it isn't, unfortunately, @Tornhoof . The requirement to need a separate database is less than desirable. I even bountied the question myself to see if someone else had a better idea though, and no one did. That does suggest it's the "correct" solution at the moment, but I dislike it. I would like to hope there's a better solution in the next version of SQL Server. I should probably, in all honestly, check to see if there's a ticket out there on Azure Feedback about the "problem".

Comment: Hi @Larnu recently I stumbled over a hack, which works even in lower versions, see my answer.

Answer (score 9):

There is an undocumented hack:

```
DECLARE @utf8 VARBINARY(MAX)=0x48656C6C6F20F09F988A;

SELECT CAST(CONCAT('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?><![CDATA[',@utf8,']]>') AS XML)
       .value('.','nvarchar(max)');
```

The result

```
Hello
```

This works even in versions without the new UTF8 collations...

**UPDATE: calling this as a function**

This can easily be wrapped in a scalar function

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.Convert_UTF8_Binary_To_NVarchar(@utfBinary VARBINARY(MAX))
RETURNS NVARCHAR(MAX)
AS
BEGIN
    RETURN
    (
    SELECT CAST(CONCAT('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?><![CDATA[',@utfBinary,']]>') AS XML)
           .value('.','nvarchar(max)')
    );
END
GO
```

Or like this as an inlined table valued function

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.Convert_UTF8_Binary_To_NVarchar(@utfBinary VARBINARY(MAX))
RETURNS TABLE
AS
    RETURN
    SELECT CAST(CONCAT('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?><![CDATA[',@utfBinary,']]>') AS XML)
           .value('.','nvarchar(max)') AS ConvertedString
GO
```

This can be used after `FROM` or - more appropriate - with `APPLY`

Comment: Nice! I wish you'd have found this when I offered a bounty on this ages ago, but if I can make another, I'll do so. :) If you can make this into a callable function, that would really be the icing on  the cake.

Comment: @Larnu just've added the icing to the cake :-)

Comment: NOw I just have to wait 24 hours -_-

Comment: @Larnu, thank you very much, sorry that I did not come by when you needed this...

Comment: I personally didn't "need" it, @Shnugo , I just didn't "like" my answer, in truth. Using a second database just to get the correct behaviour didn't sit right with me at the time, but I knew there would be ways to get it to work without it; just couldn't figure out how. The fact this doesn't need 2019 is even better though. :)

Comment: @Larnu, okay, I get that... In general I do not understand, why there is no direct (limited!) access to .Net-API. Adding own assemblies is possible, but not wanted in many cases. In this hack the string conversion seems to be handed to some API in the background, which deals with the XML as if it was read from a file. This could work in a direct call too.

Answer (score 4):

```
DECLARE @utf8Binary varbinary(max) = 0x48656C6C6F20F09F988A;
DECLARE @brokenNVarChar nvarchar(max) = concat(@utf8Binary, '' COLLATE Latin1_General_100_CI_AS_SC_UTF8);
print '@brokenNVarChar = ' +  @brokenNVarChar;
```

Answer (score -2):

You didn't say how your data is compressed or what compression algorithm was used.  But if you are using the `COMPRESS` function in SQL Server 2016 or later, you can use the `DECOMPRESS` function and then cast it to a `VARCHAR(MAX)`. Both `COMPRESS` and `DECOMPRESS` use the GZip compression algorithm.
This function will decompress an input expression value, using the GZIP algorithm. `DECOMPRESS` will return a byte array (`VARBINARY(MAX)` type).

`CAST(DECOMPRESS([compressed content here]) AS VARCHAR(MAX))`

See: [COMPRESS (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/compress-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) and [DECOMPRESS (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/decompress-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)