# OPENJSON From File and unicode chars issues

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, unicode, sql-server-2017

I am running the below query,

```
 SELECT c.*
 FROM OPENROWSET (BULK N'C:\countries-states-cities-database-master\countries.json', SINGLE_CLOB) as j
 CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(BulkColumn)
 WITH
 (
     id int ,
      name nvarchar(256),
      iso3 char(3),
      numeric_code INT,
      iso2 char(2),
      phonecode nvarchar(256),
      capital nvarchar(256),
      currency nvarchar(255),
      currency_name nvarchar(255),
      currency_symbol nvarchar(255),
      tld nvarchar(255),
      native nvarchar(255),
      region nvarchar(255),
      subregion nvarchar(255),
      timezones nvarchar(max),
      translations nvarchar(max),
      latitude decimal(10,8),
      longitude decimal(11,8),
      emoji nvarchar(191),
      emojiU nvarchar(191),
      created_at datetime,
      updated_at datetime,
      flag INT,
      wikiDataId nvarchar(255) 
 ) AS c
```

The dats is from https://github.com/dr5hn/countries-states-cities-database

I am getting data like,

```
currency_symbol tld   native
?‹              .af    ?§?????§?†?³???§?†
```

If you check JSON its like,

```
        "currency_symbol": "؋",
        "tld": ".af",
        "native": "افغانستان",
```

Comment: Just to give you something: apparently you can specify the `CODEPAGE` on the `OPENROWSET` method: [microsoft openrowset](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openrowset-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16).

Comment: @Memristor Doesn't work with `SINGLE_CLOB` or `SINGLE_NCLOB` only with a format file

Comment: Possibly you can use one fo these hacks https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64354878/convert-utf-8-varbinarymax-to-varcharmax to get a `SINGLE_BLOB` binary into a `varchar(max)`

Comment: @lptr's suggestion does work against that UTF8 encoded file https://i.stack.imgur.com/kW9Fu.png

Comment: @MartinSmith That's one of the hacks mentioned, third answer, and written by them also

Comment: Invalid collation 'Latin1_General_100_CI_AS_SC_UTF8'